# Confusion with "array var-args" as parameter

Tags: java

What does this mean? I can't tell what the first method `m` parameter declaration means.

It refuses to pass in a `String` but allows a single-dimensional array `String []` and a two-dimensional array `String[][]`. It does not allow `[][][]` or anything more.

Can someone clear this up?

```
class j{
    public static void m(String [] ...  a) {
        System.out.println("Y");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String [][] s = {};
        m(s);
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`public static void m(String [] ...  a)` means your function can accept any number of String[] as arguments, and within the function you will have an array of String[] (i.e. a String[][]) as the type for `a`. You may also directly pass a single String[][] instead of passing multiple String[].

for example...

```
String [] x = {"a", "aa", "aaa"};
String [] y = {"b", "bb", "bbb"};
String [] z = {"c", "cc", "ccc"};

//All of these are valid uses of m(...).
m(x);
m(x,y);
m(x,y,z);
```

In each case, `m` will have a two-dimensional array of Strings named `a`.

Additionally, since `a` is a `String[][]`, you may also pass in a single `String[][]` directly.

```
String[][] XYZ = {x,y,z};

//Also valid. Same behaviour as m(x,y,z);
m(XYZ);
```

Comment: Even `m()` is possible. Dont overlook this.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of supplying the variable number of arguments of type T. You can either directly list expressions that are assignment convertible to T, or you can supply a single T[].

For the specific case, that means you can either list expressions of type String[], or supply a single String[][].

Answer (score 1):

It is only a bit of syntax sugar from the compiler.

That is:

```
ReturnType withVarArgs(ParamType... params) {}
```

is mostly equivalent to:

```
ReturnType noVarArgs(ParamType[] params) {}
```

with the following differences:

- If you have variables `a`, `b`, `c` of type `ParamType`, you can call `withVarArgs` function with the syntax `withVarArgs(a, b, c)`; you would have to create an intermediary array yourself to call the `noVarArgs` variant.
- A variable arguments parameter can only specified as the last parameter;
- As pointed out in Effective Java, the behavior of `Object...` and `Object[]` will differ when you pass any array of a subtype of `Object` (e.g., let us say you want to pass a `String[]`):

  - if it is used with `Object...`, the `String[]` array object will be wrapped in a 1-element object array;
  - if it is used with `Object[]`, the `String[]` array object will be used directly because arrays in Java are covariant on their element type;